# why i cant read an object from json in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

Hello what i am trying to do is that i am importing this JSON file:

```js
[
  {
    "nombre":"Is this It",
    "año":" July 30, 2001",
    "genre":"Indie rock",
    "label":"RCA",
    "lugar":"Estados Unidos",
    "portada":"https://www.elquintobeatle.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/the-strokes-is-this-it-1-1068x1068.jpg",
    "descripcion":"asdasd.",
    "canciones":[
      {
        "numero":1,
        "titulo":"Is this It"
      },
      {
        "numero":2,
        "titulo":"The Modern Age"
      },
      {
        "numero":3,
        "titulo":"Soma"
      },
      {
        "numero":4,
        "titulo":"Barely Legal"
      },
      {
        "numero":5,
        "titulo":"Someday"
      },
      {
        "numero":6,
        "titulo":"Alone, Together"
      },
      {
        "numero":7,
        "titulo":"Last Nite"
      },
      {
        "numero":8,
        "titulo":"Hard to Explaim"
      },
      {
        "numero":9,
        "titulo":"New York City Cops"
      },
      {
        "numero":10,
        "titulo":"Trying Your Luck"
      },
      {
        "numero":11,
        "titulo":"Take It or Leave It"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nombre":"Room on Fire",
    "año":"2003",
    "genre":"Indie rock",
    "label":"RCA",
    "lugar":"Estados Unidos",
    "portada":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9f/Room_on_Fire_cover.jpg/220px-Room_on_Fire_cover.jpg",
    "descripcion":"asdasd",
    "canciones":[
      {
        "numero":1,
        "titulo":"What Ever Happened"
      },
      {
        "numero":2,
        "titulo":"Reptilia"
      },
      {
        "numero":3,
        "titulo":"Automatic Stop"
      },
      {
        "numero":4,
        "titulo":"12:51"
      },
      {
        "numero":5,
        "titulo":"You Talk Way Too Much"
      },
      {
        "numero":6,
        "titulo":"Between Love & Hate"
      },
      {
        "numero":7,
        "titulo":"Meet Me in the Bathroom"
      },
      {
        "numero":8,
        "titulo":"Under Control"
      },
      {
        "numero":9,
        "titulo":"The Way It Is"
      },
      {
        "numero":10,
        "titulo":"The End Has No End"
      },
      {
        "numero":11,
        "titulo":"I Can't Win"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```js
import * as data from '../catalogo.json';
```

then through a function I update the state of the component like this:

```
updateState(e)
{
    this.setState
    (
        {
            albumActual : data[1]
        }   
    );
}
```

THEN I WANT TO READ THE INFORMATION AND WRITE INSIDE A TABLE LIKE THIS:

```
<tr>
    <td className='celda'> Song: </td>
     <td className='celda'> 
       <ul>
            <li>
               <div> 
                    {this.state.albumActual.canciones[1].numero }
                </div> 
               </li>
        </ul>
  </td>
```

and i get the following problem:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxZx5.png)

i just don't understand why. i am just a beginner developing in react.

This is the full component:

import React from 'react'
import '../assets/css/ComponenteBarra.css';
import * as data from '../catalogo.json';

class BarraAlbumes extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.actualizarState = this.actualizarState.bind(this);
        this.state = { albumActual : []  } 
    }

```
actualizarState(e)
{
    this.setState
    (
        {
            albumActual : data[1]
        }   
    );
}

render()
{
    return(
    <div id='barra'>

            <table>
                <thead>
                    <td colSpan='7'>
                        <h1 id='tituloDeBarra' > ALBUMES </h1>
                    </td>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td> 
                        <button onClick={this.actualizarState}>
                            <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/09/The_Strokes_-_Is_This_It_cover.png/220px-The_Strokes_-_Is_This_It_cover.png' alt='portada' />
                        </button>
                   </td>

                   <td>
                       <button>
                            <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9f/Room_on_Fire_cover.jpg/220px-Room_on_Fire_cover.jpg' alt='portada' />
                       </button>
                   </td>

                   <td > 
                        <button>
                            <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/0f/FIOEstrokes.jpg/220px-FIOEstrokes.jpg' alt='portada' />
                        </button> 
                   </td>

                   <td >
                       <button>
                                <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d9/Strokes_1.jpg/220px-Strokes_1.jpg' alt='portada' />
                       </button>
                   </td>

                   <td > 
                        <button>
                            <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/91/The_Strokes_-_Comedown_Machine.jpg/220px-The_Strokes_-_Comedown_Machine.jpg' alt='portada' />
                        </button> 
                   </td>

                   <td >
                       <button>
                                <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d3/The-Strokes-Future-Present-Past-EP.jpg/220px-The-Strokes-Future-Present-Past-EP.jpg' alt='portada' />
                       </button>
                   </td>

                   <td >
                       <button>
                                <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/f8/The_Strokes_-_The_New_Abnormal.png/220px-The_Strokes_-_The_New_Abnormal.png' alt='portada' />
                       </button>
                   </td>

                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>


            <table id='tableinfo'>
                <thead>
                        <td id='titulotabla' colSpan='2'> INFORMACION DEL ALBUM </td>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td className='celda' > Nombre: </td>
                        <td className='celda' > {this.state.albumActual.nombre} </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td className='celda'> Año de Lanzamiento: </td>
                        <td className='celda'>   {this.state.albumActual.año} </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td className='celda'> Genero: </td>
                        <td className='celda'>   {this.state.albumActual.genre} </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td className='celda'> Disquera: </td>
                        <td className='celda'>   {this.state.albumActual.label} </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td className='celda'> Lugar: </td>
                        <td className='celda'>  {this.state.albumActual.lugar}  </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td className='celda'> Portada: </td>
                        <td className='celda'> <img src={this.state.albumActual.portada}  alt='foto' /> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td className='celda'> Descripcion: </td>
                        <td className='celda'> {this.state.albumActual.descripcion} </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td className='celda'> Canciones: </td>
                        <td className='celda'> 
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                     <div> 
                                            {this.state.albumActual.canciones[1].numero }
                                     </div> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
    </div>      
    )   
}
```

}

export default BarraAlbumes;

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING

Comment: Did you ask Jason's permission to be imported?

Comment: Hello, i didnt know i had to do that, but stil i can acces to the others fields of the json like nombre,año, etc. the problem is when i acces to the field "canciones"

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don't use capital-letter-words, because it means you are (angry) shouting to other people. 
Encapsulate your code in three backticks - linebreak... your code, linebreak - there backticks. Backticks are those one: \`
This prevent a broken Code-Section like you have atm. in your posting.

Comment: Oh! ok i didnt know that. just starting using this 1 hour ago. thanks for the advice.

Comment: Can you console.log and check where the values are wrong. Try debugging it.

Comment: Show your full component

Comment: Are you exporting the data? Or do you have a json loader?

Comment: Hi @DanielMontellanos please check my answer that solves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example solution:

The main point is that you have to check if the variable exists that you want to output.

```js
const data = [{
    "nombre": "Is this It",
    "año": " July 30, 2001",
    "genre": "Indie rock",
    "label": "RCA",
    "lugar": "Estados Unidos",
    "portada": "https://www.elquintobeatle.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/the-strokes-is-this-it-1-1068x1068.jpg",
    "descripcion": "asdasd.",
    "canciones": [{
        "numero": 1,
        "titulo": "Is this It"
      },
      {
        "numero": 2,
        "titulo": "The Modern Age"
      },
      {
        "numero": 3,
        "titulo": "Soma"
      },
      {
        "numero": 4,
        "titulo": "Barely Legal"
      },
      {
        "numero": 5,
        "titulo": "Someday"
      },
      {
        "numero": 6,
        "titulo": "Alone, Together"
      },
      {
        "numero": 7,
        "titulo": "Last Nite"
      },
      {
        "numero": 8,
        "titulo": "Hard to Explaim"
      },
      {
        "numero": 9,
        "titulo": "New York City Cops"
      },
      {
        "numero": 10,
        "titulo": "Trying Your Luck"
      },
      {
        "numero": 11,
        "titulo": "Take It or Leave It"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nombre": "Room on Fire",
    "año": "2003",
    "genre": "Indie rock",
    "label": "RCA",
    "lugar": "Estados Unidos",
    "portada": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9f/Room_on_Fire_cover.jpg/220px-Room_on_Fire_cover.jpg",
    "descripcion": "asdasd",
    "canciones": [{
        "numero": 1,
        "titulo": "What Ever Happened"
      },
      {
        "numero": 2,
        "titulo": "Reptilia"
      },
      {
        "numero": 3,
        "titulo": "Automatic Stop"
      },
      {
        "numero": 4,
        "titulo": "12:51"
      },
      {
        "numero": 5,
        "titulo": "You Talk Way Too Much"
      },
      {
        "numero": 6,
        "titulo": "Between Love & Hate"
      },
      {
        "numero": 7,
        "titulo": "Meet Me in the Bathroom"
      },
      {
        "numero": 8,
        "titulo": "Under Control"
      },
      {
        "numero": 9,
        "titulo": "The Way It Is"
      },
      {
        "numero": 10,
        "titulo": "The End Has No End"
      },
      {
        "numero": 11,
        "titulo": "I Can't Win"
      }
    ]
  }
]

class Album extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      albumActual: {}
    }
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this)
  }

  updateState() {
    this.setState({
      albumActual: data[1]
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick = {this.updateState}>Click</button>
        <ul>
        {
          !this.state.albumActual.canciones
            ? null
            : this.state.albumActual.canciones.map(e => {
              return (
                <li>{e.numero}: {e.titulo}</li>
              )
            })
        }
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <Album /> , document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

So, you might change this:

```
{this.state.albumActual.canciones[1].numero }
```

to

```
{
  !this.state.albumActual.canciones
    : null
    ? this.state.albumActual.canciones[1].numero
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Show you full component and how you call the function.

But Im very confident that the problem is that on the first render your data is yet not data.

You can either wrap your render method in a condition or set the state as default.

```
import * as data from '../catalogo.json';


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Set the state directly. Use props if necessary.
    this.state = {
      albuls: data
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the function is called by an event,  <button onClick={this.actualizarState}>. i would like to show the component but its too long and i dont know how show it.

Comment: You have to do a conditional render then.

Answer (score 0):

Initially this.state.albumActual is empty array as you setState with data[1] after clicking the button (in the function actualizarState). So please replace **{this.state.albumActual.canciones[1].numero }** by the following code:

```
{this.state.albumActual.canciones? this.state.albumActual.canciones[1].numero : null}
```